# Error calculating variance of a random variable squared

Tags: variance

Consider discrete random variable $Y$ that takes value -1 with probability 0.5 and value 1 with probability 0.5. Given that $E(Y) = -1*0.5+1*.5 = 0$ and $E(Y^2) = -1^2*.5+1^2*.5 = 1$,
I calculated that $Var(Y^2) = (E(Y^2))^2 - (E(Y))^4$.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: If this is a self-study question, please consider adding the corresponding tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The identity you are using is $Var(X) = E[X^2] - (E[X])^2$, and in your case you are applying the identity with $X = Y^2$. So carefully plugging in you have $Var(Y^2) = E[Y^4] - (E[Y^2])^2$.

Since it looks like you know how to compute $E[Y^2]$ and $E[Y^4]$, you should be able to complete the exercise to show that $Var(Y^2) = 0$.